# Submit without leaving page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, submit

My form

```
<form id="reservationForm" action="sendmail.php" method="post">
...
.
.
.
.
<input type="image" src="images/res-button.png" alt="Submit" class="submit" width="251" height="51px">
```

My javascript

```
$("#reservationForm").submit(function () {     

        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);

     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendmail.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                alert("Success");
                $('#reservationForm').fadeOut("slow");
            }
});
     return false;
});
```

i don't want to run any validation because i have user 'required' in all  types. i just want to send data to my php while staying at the same contact form. but this only load my php file and send the e-mail. looks like it dosen't run my javascript. please help

Comment: your form is missing...

Comment: change `action` to self (same page as where the form is)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the event argument in the callback. Change this line as follows and it should work:

```
$("#reservationForm").submit(function (e) {   
...
```

EDIT: BTW: The .submit event handler of jQuery short hand is deprecated. You should be `using .on('submit', ...`instead.

Comment: will it not load the other page still? I saw in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669804/submit-a-form-without-leaving-page) an answer stating you also need to add `preventDefault();`, maybe that's the trick...

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast on that one :)

Comment: thanks for help. but still its taking me to php file. :(

Comment: $("#reservationForm").on('submit', function (e) {     

            e.preventDefault();
            var $form = $(this);

         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sendmail.php',
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
     alert("Success");
     $('#reservationForm').fadeOut("slow");
                }
 });
   return false;
});

Comment: http://thewildholidayresorts.com/demo/reservations.php

this is the link for my website